# Text classification using Doc2vec and evaluated by cross validation

Tags: python, cross-validation, text-classification, doc2vec

Recently I am doing a text classification problem and want to use Doc2vec for experiment. I googled and saw the tutorial post of [@susanli2016](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-doc2vec-logistic-regression-9da9947b43f4). I was wondering how can I use cross validation to evaluate instead of train/test split in this case? 
P.s.: As I couldn't really find anyone who use cv for evaluation, is train/test split better here?

Here is her code:

```
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
def tokenize_text(text):
    tokens = []
    for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(text):
        for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sent):
            if len(word) < 2:
                continue
            tokens.append(word.lower())
    return tokens
train_tagged = train.apply(
    lambda r: TaggedDocument(words=tokenize_text(r['narrative']), tags=[r.Product]), axis=1)
test_tagged = test.apply(
    lambda r: TaggedDocument(words=tokenize_text(r['narrative']), tags=[r.Product]), axis=1)

model_dbow = Doc2Vec(dm=0, vector_size=300, negative=5, hs=0, min_count=2, sample = 0, workers=cores)
model_dbow.build_vocab([x for x in tqdm(train_tagged.values)])

def vec_for_learning(model, tagged_docs):
    sents = tagged_docs.values
    targets, regressors = zip(*[(doc.tags[0], model.infer_vector(doc.words, steps=20)) for doc in sents])
    return targets, regressors

y_train, X_train = vec_for_learning(model_dbow, train_tagged)
y_test, X_test = vec_for_learning(model_dbow, test_tagged)
logreg = LogisticRegression(n_jobs=1, C=1e5)
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score
print('Testing accuracy %s' % accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Here is my thought:

```
tagged = df.apply(
    lambda r: TaggedDocument(words=tokenize_text(r['Text']), tags=[r.label]), axis=1)

doc = vec_for_learning(model_dbow, tagged)
text_clf = SVC(C=1, kernel= 'linear', max_iter= 1000, tol=0.0001, probability=True)

scores = cross_validate(text_clf, doc, df['label'], 
                        cv=10, return_train_score=False)
sorted(scores.keys())                             
scores['test_score']
```

but I got the following error message:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-77-105f56d4a65a> in <module>()
      1 scores = cross_validate(text_clf, doc, df['label'], 
----> 2                         cv=10, return_train_score=False)
      3 sorted(scores.keys())
      4 
      5 scores['test_score']

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score, return_estimator, error_score)
    223 
    224     """
--> 225     X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
    226 
    227     cv = check_cv(cv, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in indexable(*iterables)
    258         else:
    259             result.append(np.array(X))
--> 260     check_consistent_length(*result)
    261     return result
    262 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    233     if len(uniques) > 1:
    234         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 235                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    236 
    237 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 2234]
```

I don't know where did I do wrong and how to fix it.

Since I am very new to python and NLP domain, I would be glad if someone can give me a hint on this so my work can proceed:)

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Hi. Please give the full stack trace and not just the `ValueError: ...` line.

Comment: Unrelated to your error stack, but relevant: your `model_dbow` is never trained, only initialized (via the constructor and then `build_vocab()`). Without training, any results that model gives will be nonsense.

Comment: Related to your conceptual Q: cross-validation is essentially just doing many train-test splits automatically. So in general, it *can* be done anywhere you previously did just a single train/test split. It'll require more time/effort & its estimates will be a little more reliable, but the extra time/effort may not be strictly necessary. Note your code only shows a `Doc2Vec` model using a single training set - not trying alternate D2V models based on the different CV splits. (As `Doc2Vec` isn't a sklearn-native class, that's a little harder to do, but `D2VTransformer` in `gensim` may help.)

Comment: Regarding your specific error: as it arises inside `sklearn`, after your call to `cross_validate()` (which is just compiling CV evaluation data for the `SVC` classifier), it's almost certainly due to the `doc` value being passed-in not being of the proper expected object-type/format/shape. Look at that value closely, and compare it to any working examples of `cross_validate()` you can find. The cause of the error likely lies there.